# Why did this incorrect partial fraction decomposition produce the correct answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

I was reviewing a classmate (call him Bob)'s work on an integration of a rational expression (although integration is involved, it's beyond the scope of this question).

The problem was:

$$\int\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3x + 2} dx$$

Bob attempted to use decomposition to split this into partial fractions. I had been taught that partial fraction decomposition can only be used on a $N(x)/D(x)$ if and only if the $deg(N(x)) < deg(D(x))$, so I knew that Bob's method was incorrect from the start; however, he still got the correct answer.

His work was as follows:

$$\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3x + 2} = \frac{A}{x+2} + \frac{B}{x+1} $$

$$
\begin{align}
x^2 + 1 &= A(x + 1) + B(x + 2) \\
&= (A + B)x + (A + 2B)
\end{align}
$$

Comparing the coefficients, he wrote:

$$
\begin{align}
1 &= A + 2B \\
x^2 &= (A + B)x \Rightarrow x = A + B \quad\color{red}{(wrong!)}
\end{align}
$$

Solving the system, he then wrote 
$$
\begin{align}
1 &= A + 2B \Rightarrow A = 1-2B\\
x &= A + B \Rightarrow x = (1-2B)+B = 1-B \Rightarrow B=1-x \\
\text{Thus, } A &= 1-2(1-x) = 2x - 1
\end{align}
$$

which meant his "decomposition" produced the partial fractions of

$$\frac{x^2 + 1}{x^2 + 3x + 2} = \frac{2x-1}{x+2} + \frac{1-x}{x+1}$$

Although the method was not typical, it ended with fractions that are equivalent to the original, and thus integrates to the correct answer.

Is this just some lucky coincidence, or is there an exception to the rule of when to use partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: Why is wrong the wrong part? Because you may be dividing by zero?

Comment: Basically, he made an assumption which was wrong (that $A,B$ can be chosen to be constant) and then in the course of doing the algebra contradicted that assumption. But then he stuck with the new situation and got a correct answer (though for integration a long division step will still be required). It's not so bad, but in general you will have a problem: if $A,B$ aren't constant, then what restrictions *do* they have to satisfy? Why couldn't you have concluded $(A+B)x=1,A+2B=x^2$ or something?

Comment: I'm sorry for being confused, but what's wrong with decomposing fractions when the degree of the numerator is equal to or greater than the denominator?

Comment: @SimpleArt: It can’t be done. If you set up the partial fractions with the numerators that the method prescribes and then recombine the partial fractions into a single fraction over its least common denominator, this new fraction has the same denominator as the original one and a numerator whose degree is smaller than that of the denominator. If the original fraction had a numerator whose degree was greater than or equal to the degree of the denominator, that numerator cannot possibly be equal to the new one with the unknown constants, and there will be no way to solve for the constants.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are implying that the degree of the denominator must be larger than the degree of the numerator?  If so,$$\frac{2x-1}{x+2}+\frac{1-x}{x+1}=1-\frac5{x+2}+\frac2{x+1}?$$

Comment: His algebra is correct, so the decomposition that he obtained is indeed equal to the original fraction and therefore will have the same integral. As **Ian** said, he’ll still have to divide out the fractions in order to do the integration(s), but (a) this is very easy to do, and (b) the resulting integrations are very easy, so he has in fact found a reasonable way to perform the original integration. As a teacher I’d be in a quandary: what he’s done is correct and is guaranteed to work, assuming that he finished it off correctly, but it very strongly suggests that he’s missed an important ...

Comment: ... fact about the method of partial fractions.

Comment: @SimpleArt: Yes, if the method of partial fractions had been performed correctly, the initial step of dividing out would have left $1-\frac{3x+1}{(x+2)(x+1)}$, and the actual partial fraction decomposition would then have produced exactly what you have.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Why must we do that?  Does it make the problem easier?

Comment: @SimpleArt: See my first comment to you: the standard method of decomposing a fraction into partial fractions simply does not work if the degree of the numerator is not less than the degree of the denominator. What ‘Bob’ did here is *not* the method of partial fractions.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Last Comment (sorry): What's wrong with the form 'Bob' has, does it not work out right or something?  I don't get why we have to decompose the fractions like so.  Never mind, I found a link as to why we do such things.  Thanks!

Comment: @SimpleArt: See my comment beginning *His algebra is correct* and the earlier comment by **Ian**. ‘Bob’ got lucky: he found a correct algebraic manipulation that reduced the original integrand to one that he could handle. What he did *was* algebraically correct, but it was somewhat *ad hoc*: he did not employ a technique guaranteed to produce a form that he could handle. The real method of partial fractions *is* guaranteed to produce such a form, but in order to apply it, you must first divide out to get a polynomial plus a ‘proper’ fraction, one whose numerator has lower degree than its ...

Comment: ... denominator. In other words, for this specific problem there is nothing actually wrong with the approach that ‘Bob’ used, but that approach does not generalize well; the real method of partial fractions does.